# Implementing a Depth First Traversal based on a strategy in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Good day.

I have a problem implementing a depth first search based on a Strategy, which is defined in a strategy.py class. There is also a graph and a traversal class. The traversal class is responsible for well, traversing the graph.

The strategy class is as follows:

```
class Strategy:

init_priority = 0

def __init__(self, init_pri = 0):
    self.init_priority = init_pri

def init(self, graph, node):
    """Called at beginning of traversal process.  Expected that
    this will carry out any necessary initialisation for the
    specific traversal process
    """
    pass

def visit(self, node, pri):
    """Called whenever NODE is visited by a traversal process.
    PRI is the priority associated with the node in the priority
    queue used by the traversal process.
    """
    pass

def complete(self, node):
    """Called at the end of all the processing performed in visiting NODE.
    """
    pass

def discover(self, nbr, node, weight, pri):
    """Return the priority that should be associated with NBR when it is 
    added to the priority queue.

    Called whenever NBR is discovered for the first time.  NODE
    is the node from which the neighbour was discovered, and
    WEIGHT is the value on the edge from NODE to NBR.  PRI is the
    value associated with NODE in the priority queue, at the time
    of discovering NBR.
    """

def rediscover(self, nbr, node, weight, pri):
    """Return the priority that should be associated with NBR when it is 
    added to the priority queue.

    Called whenever NBR is rediscovered.  NODE is the node from
    which the neighbour is rediscovered, and WEIGHT is the value
    associated with the edge from NODE to NBR.  PRI is the
    priority of NODE in the priority queue.  It is provided in
    case it is relevant to the traversal strategy (e.g. for Dijkstra's)
    """
    pass

def getResult(self):
    """Called at the end of the traversal process.  It should
    return whatever is relevant or appropriate for the type of
    traversal implemented by this strategy.
    """
    pass
```

I managed to implement a breadth first search as follows:

```
class BreadthFirst(Strategy):

sequence = None             # the sequence in which nodes are visted
treeEdges = None            # the edges used to visit the nodes traversed
root = -1                   # the origin of the traversal
last_pri = -1               # the most recent priority used

def __init__(self):
    """The BreadthFirst strategy uses an initial priority of 0"""
    Strategy(0)

def init(self, graph, node):
    """We reset all our state information so that old traversals do not
    affect the one that is about to start."""

    self.last_pri = self.init_priority
    self.treeEdges = []
    self.sequence = []
    self.root = -1

def visit(self, node, src, pri):
    """Breadth first traversal pays no attention to weights."""
    self.sequence.append(node)
    if src == -1:
        self.root = node
    else:
        self.treeEdges.append((src, node))

def complete(self, node):
    pass

def discover(self, nbr, node, pri):
    """Want FIFO behaviour so increment priority (ignore weights)"""
    self.last_pri += 1
    return self.last_pri

def rediscover(self, nbr, node, pri):
    """Rules for rediscovery same as for discovery (because weights are
    ignored)"""
    self.last_pri += 1
    return self.last_pri

def getResult(self):
    """Return the details of the traversal as a dictionary."""
    return {"origin":self.root, 
            "tree":self.treeEdges, 
            "sequence":self.sequence}
```

Depth first is giving me a hassle of a time though. Here's what I have so far:

```
class DepthFirst(Strategy):

forward = None             # the forward sequence in which nodes are visted
back = None                # the backward sequence in which nodes are visited
treeEdges = None           # the edges used to visit the nodes traversed              
cross = None
root = -1                   # the origin of the traversal
last_pri = -1               # the most recent priority used

def __init__(self):
    """The DepthFirst strategy uses an initial priority of 0"""
    Strategy(0)

def init(self, graph, node):
    """Called at beginning of traversal process.  Expected that
    this will carry out any necessary initialisation for the
    specific traversal process
    """
    self.last_pri = self.init_priority
    self.treeEdges = []
    self.forward = []
    self.back = []
    self.cross = []

def visit(self, node, src, pri):
    """Called whenever NODE is visited by a traversal process.
    PRI is the priority associated with the node in the priority
    queue used by the traversal process.
    """
    self.forward.append(node)
    if src == -1:
        self.root = node
    else:
        self.treeEdges.append((src, node))


def complete(self, node):
    """Called at the end of all the processing performed in visiting NODE.
    """
    if node not in self.forward:
        self.cross.append(node)

def discover(self, nbr, node, pri):
    """Return the priority that should be associated with NBR when it is 
    added to the priority queue.

    Called whenever NBR is discovered for the first time.  NODE
    is the node from which the neighbour was discovered, and
    WEIGHT is the value on the edge from NODE to NBR.  PRI is the
    value associated with NODE in the priority queue, at the time
    of discovering NBR.
    """
    self.forward.append((node, nbr))
    self.last_pri -= 1
    return self.last_pri

def rediscover(self, nbr, node, pri):
    """Return the priority that should be associated with NBR when it is 
    added to the priority queue.

    Called whenever NBR is rediscovered.  NODE is the node from
    which the neighbour is rediscovered, and WEIGHT is the value
    associated with the edge from NODE to NBR.  PRI is the
    priority of NODE in the priority queue.  It is provided in
    case it is relevant to the traversal strategy (e.g. for Dijkstra's)
    """
    self.back.append((nbr, node))
    self.last_pri -= 1
    return self.last_pri

def getResult(self):
    """Called at the end of the traversal process.  It should
    return whatever is relevant or appropriate for the type of
    traversal implemented by this strategy.
    """
    return {"tree":self.treeEdges,
            "forward":self.forward,
            "back":self.back,
            "cross":self.cross}
```

Any tips, pointers? They would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you were just writing the two, you'd do the usual iterative loop, using a stack for DFS and a queue for BFS.  here you are unifying those with a priority queue.  so you need to make the priorities up so that those two behaviours come out.  for DFS that means that every time you add something it has higher priority than before (so it comes out before what's already in there) - an increasing positive number is fine.  for BFS it needs to be lower than anything you have added so far (so it comes out after what's already in there) - a decreasing negative number works well.

this is just my take from scanning your code.  i may be wrong and i'm not going to look in detail - i just thought it was an interesting way of looking at things that might help.

ps it's normal to tag homework with "homework".  if you don't, people will bitch.